# Can we construct a given angle again using only compass and ruler?

Tags: geometry

[image]

The figure above shows an angle $\angle AOB$. Is it possible to construct angle $\angle COA = \angle AOB$ using just a compass and a ruler of infinite length ? ( initially we are given just $\angle AOB$ and have to construct $\angle COA$ )

Comment: It can be done by drawing an arc, resetting the compass, drawing a second arc, and then drawing a straight line through two points

Comment: Use the compass to draw a circle $S_1$ around $O$, intersecting $OA$ at $C$ and intersecting $OB$ at $D$. Use the compass again to draw the circle $S_2$ around $D$ of radius $DC$. The circles $S_1,S_2$ intersect at $C$ and at one other point $E$. The ray $OE$ is what you want.

Comment: "An ruler of an infinite length" +1 for the humour

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AkvNo6PQsRs

Comment: In fact, we only need a compass to construct the desired point. The ruler is only needed to draw the line.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Thanks alot. Indeed a helpful video :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nicely worded theorem from "A Readable Introduction to Real Mathematics" By Rosenthal$^3$ (there's three of them) which states:

*Any given angle can be copied using only a straightedge and compass*

*proof* Let an angle $ABC$ be given. We construct an angle equal to $\angle ABC$ with vertex $G$ on any other line. To do this, draw any arc of any circle (of radius, say, $r$) centered at $B$ that intersects both $BA$ and $BC$. Label the points of intersection $D$ and $E$. Draw the circles of radius $r$ centered at $G$. Use $H$ to label the point where that circle intersects the line containing $G$. Then adjust the compass to be able to make circles of radius $DE$. Put the point of the compass at $H$ and draw a portion of the circle that intersects the circle centered at $G$; call that point of the intersection $I$. Draw line segments connecting $D$ to $E$ and $I$ to $H$.

Then $IH=DE$, since $IH$ is the radius of a circle with radius $DE$. Also draw line segment $GI$. The lengths of $BD, BE, GI$ and $GH$ are all equal to $r$. It follows by side-side-side that triangle $BDE$ is congruent to triangle $GIH$. Thus, $\angle IGH$ is a copy of $\angle ABC$.